# GcmNetworkManager perodic task handling

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I need to schedule a task that runs every 24 hours to get some small data from the remote server. **[GcmNetworkManager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager)** seems to be a prefect candidate as I need to support sdk 15+. (JobScheduler is only 21+).

The way I am achieving this by extending Application. **onCreate**, I create a PeriodicTask with specific tag and I call **.setUpdateCurrent(false)** (So 1st one gets scheduled and subsequent tasks should be ignored as they should not update the existing task).

In the documentation I read

> Important: When Google Play Services or the client app is updated, all scheduled tasks will be removed. GcmNetworkManager invokes the client app’s onInitializeTasks(). Override this function to reschedule necessary tasks.

In my scenario, it should not matter as onCreate of the Application I am always creating a update task. Is there a better way than that I am doing? (Also I wish there was a way to check if there is a pending periodic task with a given tag)

Comment: Just a quick question: Can you point me to the method (or documentation) that requires you to use SDK 15+ for GcmNetworkManager? I'm using it in an app that otherwise only requires SDK level 5 and haven't found a reason to change this yet. But I may have missed something! If I did, please let me know! It'd be important... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are listening for [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED) in a `BroadcastReceiver` (and scheduling your task there as well), you should still override `onInitializeTasks()` to create your same `PeriodicTask`. Otherwise, there may be time between when your app is updated by the Google Play Store and when it is manually run by the user where you have no periodic task scheduled.

Comment: Thanks Ian, according to documentation `onInitializeTasks()` is not called when app is first installed only when its updated. That being said, I will have duplicate code setting up the task and also keeping track of what tasks need to be rescheduled. Is there a better way? On a diff note how is PerodicTask rescheduled if I return "RESULT_RESCHEDULE" from that job? Does it follow standard guide line of trying after x number and 2x.. 3X before giving up? Does it even make sense for periodic job to return RESULT_RESCHEDULE on error?

Comment: You say that like your onIntializeTasks() and Application `onCreate()` couldn't share the same set of code (a static method that takes a `Context` would be enough). The different results affect the `PeriodicTask` just fine (in fact, `RESULT_FAILURE` really only makes sense in terms of `PeriodicTask` to stop trying until the next scheduled sync). If you have temporary errors you expect might clear up on their own - that would be the perfect case for exponential backoff.

Comment: just to clarify, even if I build a periodic task with **`setPersisted`**, I would still need to reschedule using `onInitializeTasks()`? I would think if [PeriodicTask](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/PeriodicTask.Builder.html#setPersisted(boolean)) persisted, I wouldn't need to reschedule it again? (Note: Also I am scheduling a PreodicTask on my Application.onCrate with updateCurrent false as I only want 1 task to be active)

Comment: Per the [setPersisted() documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/Task.Builder.html#setPersisted(boolean)), `setPersisted()` only involves persisting over reboots, nothing more.

Comment: GcmNetworkManager depends on GPServices. You'll need to check the availability of GPS on the device (method "checkPlayServicesAvailable" in this Google example https://goo.gl/VlHn1K).

Checking for GPServices used to be recommended to do on the onResume() method in the main activity (used to be here https://goo.gl/JqfX9q).

My first approach was on the Application onCreate, but now I'm scheduling the task on MainActivity after checking the availability of Google Play Services and as well on the onInitializeTasks() method and overriding the task. I'm not sure this is the best approach neither.